# Align text between two vertical lines in plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I center text with `text()` (or any more suitable function) directly between specified spacers? Basically, I want to just use the `x` and `y` arguments in `text()`, but using the 'center' of the text.

I tried: Appending white spaces didn't work and shift based on number of characters was inconsistent, and the documentation doesn't mention anything about justifying strings to center.

```
%% create figure
x=[2 5]; %spacer var
figure; hold on;
axis([0 10 0 10])

%create lines based on spacer var
line([x(1) x(1)],ylim)
line([x(2) x(2)],ylim)

%silly formatting
grid on
axis square
xticks(0:10); yticks(0:10);
set(findall(gcf,'type','line'),'linewidth',3)

%generate text between vertical lines
y = ylim; %get ylimits
text(mean([0 x(1)]),y(2)*.8,'Label_1','FontSize',10)
text(mean([x(1) x(2)]),y(2)*.8,'Label_2','FontSize',10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Text Alignment With Respect to Centre

Using the `'HorizontalAlignment'` property and setting it to `'center'` may help in achieving the alignment in between the sections divided by the vertical lines. Here I initialize each text annotation to variables `Text_1` and `Text_2` and set their `'HorizontalAlignment'` properties respectively.

### Code Snippet:

```
Text_1 = text(mean([0 x(1)]),y(2)*.8,'Label_1','FontSize',10);
Text_2 = text(mean([x(1) x(2)]),y(2)*.8,'Label_2','FontSize',10);

set(Text_1,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
set(Text_2,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
```

---

[image: Text Horizontal Alignment]

### Full Script:

```
%% create figure
x=[2 5]; %spacer var
figure; hold on;
axis([0 10 0 10])

%create lines based on spacer var
line([x(1) x(1)],ylim)
line([x(2) x(2)],ylim)

%silly formatting
grid on
axis square
xticks(0:10); yticks(0:10);
set(findall(gcf,'type','line'),'linewidth',3)

%generate text between vertical lines
y = ylim; %get ylimits
Text_1 = text(mean([0 x(1)]),y(2)*.8,'Label_1','FontSize',10);
Text_2 = text(mean([x(1) x(2)]),y(2)*.8,'Label_2','FontSize',10);

set(Text_1,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
set(Text_2,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: awesome - I missed this property! Thanks for this very aesthetic answer, *running this codeline after figure generation* (that I get from the answer) is the minimum variant. `set(findall(gcf,'type','text'),'HorizontalAlignment','center')`